# ¿Cómo tener una referencia circular entre clases y evitar StackOverflow error?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy haciendo un proyecto y para ello estoy utilizando los patrones de diseño DAO y Factory conjuntamente, por lo que divido la lógica de la vista.

Tengo una ventana **VistaContacto** con **JTextField** encapsulados y con un botón ***Guardar***.

El código de la ventana es el siguiente:

```
package Vista;

import DAO.Contactable;
import DAO.ContactoDAOAdmin;

public class VistaContacto extends javax.swing.JFrame {
ContactoDAOAdmin factory= new ContactoDAOAdmin();
Contactable contacto= factory.ContactoFactory();

public VistaContacto() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void initComponents() {

    txtNombre = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txtApellido = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    btnGuardar = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    btnGuardar.setText("Guardar");
    btnGuardar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnGuardarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(txtNombre)
                        .addComponent(txtApellido, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 176, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(141, 141, 141)
                    .addComponent(btnGuardar)))
            .addContainerGap(183, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(48, 48, 48)
            .addComponent(txtNombre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(37, 37, 37)
            .addComponent(txtApellido, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 66, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(btnGuardar)
            .addGap(33, 33, 33))
    );

    pack();                      

private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    contacto.Guardar();
}                                          

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VistaContacto.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VistaContacto.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VistaContacto.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VistaContacto.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new VistaContacto().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private javax.swing.JButton btnGuardar;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtApellido;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtNombre;                   

public javax.swing.JTextField getTxtNombre(){
    return txtNombre;
}

public javax.swing.JTextField getTxtApellido(){
    return txtApellido;
}

}
```

Llamo a los **JTextField** encapsulados de la ventana **VistaContacto** a una nueva clase llamada **ContactoDAOImpl** y los utilizo en el método **Guardar**, este a su vez lo guarda en un **ArrayList** de **Contactos**.

El código es el siguiente:

```
package DAO;

import Vista.VistaContacto;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ContactoDAOImpl implements Contactable{

VistaContacto ventanac= new VistaContacto();

private ArrayList<Controlador.Contacto> arreglo= new ArrayList();

@Override
public void Guardar(){
    arreglo.add(new Controlador.Contacto(ventanac.getTxtNombre().getText(), ventanac.getTxtApellido().getText()));
}

}
```

Y el código de la clase **Contacto** es este:

```
package Controlador;

public class Contacto {

private String nombre;
private String apellido;

public Contacto(){

}

public Contacto(String nombre, String apellido){
    nombre= this.nombre;
    apellido= this.apellido;
}

public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre= nombre;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

}
```

Para llamar a la clase **ContactoDAOImpl** en **VistaContacto** y utilizar el método **Guardar** utilizo el modelo **Factory** y lo implemento de este modo:

```
package DAO;

public class ContactoDAOAdmin {

public Contactable ContactoFactory(){
    return new ContactoDAOImpl();
}

}
```

Al ejecutar todas estas clases se produce un **StackOverFlowError** por el tipo de recursión que hago, llamar a **VistaContacto** desde **ContactoDAOImpl** y viceversa, esto me produce un error de dependencia circulares que es lo que produce el error anteriormente explicado.

Aquí esta parte del stacktrace disponible:

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:505)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
at Vista.VistaContacto.<init>(VistaContacto.java:11)
at DAO.ContactoDAOImpl.<init>(ContactoDAOImpl.java:9)
at DAO.ContactoDAOAdmin.ContactoFactory(ContactoDAOAdmin.java:7)
at Vista.VistaContacto.<init>(VistaContacto.java:9)
```

Lo que quisiera que me explicaran es cómo puedo evitar este tipo error al llamar una clase desde otra y viceversa o si estoy aplicando mal la lógica.

Answer (score 4):

Tu diseño es extraño. Si estás haciendo una aplicación estructurada en capas, lo usual es que la capa de vista conozca solo a la capa de lógica de negocio, y que la capa de lógica de negocio conozca solo a la capa de acceso a datos (dao), y que la capa de acceso a datos conozca la forma de interactuar con tus datos. Actualmente, tu capa dao tiene conocimiento de la vista, lo cual genera las referencias circulares, principalmente en el constructor, así:

```
public class VistaContacto extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    //aquí
    ContactoDAOAdmin factory= new ContactoDAOAdmin();
    Contactable contacto= factory.ContactoFactory();

    public VistaContacto() {
        initComponents();
    }
}

public class ContactoDAOImpl implements Contactable{
    //aquí, para obtener los datos para crear el contacto
    VistaContacto ventanac= new VistaContacto();
    @Override
    public void Guardar(){
        arreglo.add(new Controlador.Contacto(
            ventanac.getTxtNombre().getText(),
            ventanac.getTxtApellido().getText()));
    }
}

public class ContactoDAOAdmin {
    //aquí
    public Contactable ContactoFactory() {
        return new ContactoDAOImpl();
    }
}
```

Te diría que mantengas tu diseño lo más simple que puedas. En este caso, en lugar de enviar la vista y hacer tu clase `ContactoDAOImpl` más reutilizable por diferentes vistas, te recomiendo dos cosas:

1. Eliminar la asociación entre `ContactoDAOImpl` y `VistaContacto`. Esto eliminará la referencia circular y tu problema de StackOverflowError.
2. En el método `Guardar` (que debería ser `guardar`) debes recibir como argumento el `Contacto` con el que vas a trabajar. De esta manera, otras clases pueden utilizar a esta implementación de dao sin brindarle su detalle de implementación de cómo obtienen los datos del `Contacto`.

Tu clase `ContactoDAOImpl` quedaría así:

```
public class ContactoDAOImpl implements Contactable {
    @Override
    public void guardar(Contacto contacto){
        arreglo.add(contacto);
    }
}
```

Ojo que deberás modificar la interfaz para reflejar este cambio:

```
public interface Contactable {
    void guardar(Contacto contacto);
    //otros métodos en la interfaz
}
```

Y en tu clase `VistaContacto` deberás cambiarla para soportar los cambios hechos a la interfaz:

```
public class VistaContacto extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    contacto.guardar(
        new Contacto(
            getTxtNombre().getText(),
            getTxtApellido().getText()));
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Huele muy mal que un metodo de un DAO instancie un JFrame

Comment: Ahora que me han explicado es cierto, además de que esta mal, hace que la clase tenga un bajo acoplamiento

Answer (score 3):

El problema se da cuando se instancia `ventanac` en `ContactoDAOImpl`. Si quitas éste atributo `VistaContacto ventanac` de la clase `ContactoDAOImpl` y pasas el mismo como parámetro del método `Guardar(){...}` solucionarías la dependencia circular.

Como consejo aparte, deberías cambiar el nombre de los paquetes ya que como *buena práctica* estos nombres deben ser un nombre de dominio inverso, es decir, si el dominio es `www.dominio.edu`, los paquetes deberían ser `edu.dominio.dao`, `edu.dominio.util`, etc.

Por último, el nombre de los métodos de una clase debe iniciar con minúsculas, Ej: `public void guardar(String valor){..}`.

Comment: Te refieres a poner la instacia de 'VentanaContacto' dentro del método.

De esta manera:

'    public void Guardar(){
        VistaContacto ventanac= new VistaContacto();
        arreglo.add(new Controlador.Contacto(ventanac.getTxtNombre().getText(), ventanac.getTxtApellido().getText()));
    }'

Comment: @David no, se refiere a que `VistaContacto` sea argumento del método. Aunque eso sería un diseño muy raro.

Comment: @Luiggi Crees que puede haber una mejor manera de implementar una solución

Comment: @David sí, acabo de publicar una respuesta al respecto.